# Finding equation of plane normal to a line.

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

How to find the equation of the plane which passes through the point $(3, -3, 1)$ and normal to the line joining the points $(3, 2, -1)$ and $(2, -1, 5)$ ?

Comment: What are your efforts ?  What are the dr's of the line joining the points ?. Then how would you write the equation of the plane which is normal to the line (use dr's as coefficients).  There is plenty of material out there, please look up first and then ask so that someone can really help you.

Answer (score 2):

the vector between (3,2,-1) and (2,-1,5) is
$$v=(3-2)i+(2+1)j+(-1-5)k$$
$$v=i+3j-6k$$
the vector $v$ is normal to the plane so we can use the following equation to find the plane equation
$$A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0)+C(z-z_0)=0$$ 
so that $$A=v_x=1, B=v_y=3, and C=v_z=-6$$
$(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(3,-3,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

Let the equation of the plane be $ax+by+cz+d=0$

The normal vector to the plane will be parallel to the given line passing through the points $(3, 2, -1)$ & $(2, -1, 5)$ Hence, the direction ratios of the normal vector to the plane are calculated as follows $$a=3-2=1, b=2-(-1)=3, c=-1-5=-6$$ hence, the equation of the plane is $$x+3y-6z+d=0$$ but the plane passes through the given point $(3, -3, 1)$ hence $$3+3(-3)-6(1)+d=0\iff d=12$$

substituting the value $d=12$, the equation of the plane is $$\color{red}{x+3y-6z+12=0}$$